# Выбор компилятора при сборке проекта Qt

Tags: qt, visual-c++, mingw, qmake

Имеется Qt 5.1.1 для msvc2010 и mingw792_32, первым ставился msvc2010.
Пробовал собрать проект командой:

```
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=..." "LIBS+=-l..." ibase.pro
nmake
```

Все получилось. 
Теперь вопрос, как сделать то же самое, но c использованием компилятора mingw?

```
C:\Windows\System32>qmake -query
QT_SYSROOT:
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010
QT_INSTALL_DATA:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:C:/Qt/Docs/Qt-5.5
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010/include
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010/lib
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010/bin
QT_INSTALL_BINS:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010/bin
QT_INSTALL_TESTS:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010/tests
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010/plugins
QT_INSTALL_IMPORTS:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010/imports
QT_INSTALL_QML:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010/qml
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010/translations
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION:
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES:C:/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.5
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS:C:/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.5
QT_HOST_PREFIX:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010
QT_HOST_DATA:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010
QT_HOST_BINS:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010/bin
QT_HOST_LIBS:C:/Qt/5.5/msvc2010/lib
QMAKE_SPEC:win32-msvc2010
QMAKE_XSPEC:win32-msvc2010
QMAKE_VERSION:3.0
QT_VERSION:5.5.1
```

Есть конечно параметр **-spec** для qmake, если его задать:

```
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=..." "LIBS+=-l..." -spec win32-g++ ibase.pro
```

то в Makefile.Release значения для компилятора изменятся с cl и link на соответствующие. Но переменные QT_INSTALL* будут указывать на папки связанные с msvc2010.

Думаю, использования параметра **-spec** недостаточно.
Каким же способом можно компилировать 1 проект разными наборами компиляторов?

Comment: Я советую использовать в качестве сборки CMake, и уже пользователь или ты должен будешь указать QT_INSTALL вручную через переменные среды или -DQT_INSTALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала нужно запустить "Командную строку Qt MinGW" и там запускать:

```
    cd /d <путь к проекту>
    qmake <нужные параметры>
    mingw32-make
```

Вот так и собирается.

Comment: К этому же и пришёл, только другим путём ).

Comment: В папках `C:\Qt\5.5\<msvc2010, mingw492_32>\bin` находятся _свои_ версии `qmake`, каждая из которых использует свои переменные QT_INSTALL_*, соответственно и ссылаются на папки с `include` для соответствующих компиляторов.